# How to plot image.mat in Wolfram

Tags: image-processing, import

I have a picture that saved in ".mat" format. I am interested in plotting it with WL. But I get an empty image

```
oPic = Import["img.mat", "Data"];
Image[oPic]

oPic = {{{150.197,149.344,149.393,148.436,151.044,149.871,150.889,149.484,149.565,147.757,150.495,149.836,149.544,150.041,148.522,147.742,149.057,151.015,148.497,149.725,149.176,151.4,150.565,149.079,150.487,149.99,152.039,151.943,149.946,150.851,148.769,149.183,149.198,151.71,149.607,151.312,148.766,149.39,149.698,150.587,150.71,150.472,150.684,151.185,148.925,151.622,150.376,150.215,150.547,150.068,150.947,153.483,150.678,150.635,150.57,149.511,149.583,148.596,150.269,150.631},{150.486,149.129,149.683,149.515,151.345,149.887,150.853,147.354,149.866,150.262,149.737,150.078,150.594,149.082,150.182,149.961,149.492,150.534,152.888,149.671,149.249,149.451,147.134,149.094,149.034,150.542,149.104,148.622,151.022,151.977,148.378,149.939,149.116,150.54,150.148,150.547,149.831,150.4,150.769,150.732,150.216,149.021,150.187,150.446,150.663,150.392,149.217,151.128,149.148,151.775,151.095,150.838,149.388,149.845,148.98,149.949,149.638,151.06,152.666,150.787},{151.127,150.644,149.755,148.448,150.451,151.062,148.563,151.443,150.208,150.231,148.641,150.101,150.941,148.787,150.723,152.653,149.77,147.624,149.539,150.225,150.008,149.651,150.534,150.415,151.251,149.051,149.511,149.532,151.974,149.157,150.455,151.41,151.71,149.833,150.245,149.673,150.,148.648,149.513,149.785,149.104,150.812,150.927,149.538,149.084,149.435,149.695,150.58,151.325,151.394,149.933,147.745,150.712,150.516,147.,147.,151.345,150.475,150.439,150.558},{150.444,150.18,149.672,151.753,150.541,150.288,150.21,148.338,152.296,150.937,147.224,151.117,150.146,149.31,149.483,152.219,150.664,148.901,152.474,149.071,149.293,149.949,149.717,150.853,149.249,151.432,149.788,148.8,150.335,150.278,148.589,150.092,148.264,148.964,149.655,149.31,149.59,148.879,149.08,149.375,152.54,151.399,150.233,152.5,149.784,150.612,149.247,149.814,149.799,149.931,151.047,150.561,151.594,148.555,147.,147.,151.06,150.471,151.703,150.319},{149.473,149.25,152.392,148.122,150.462,150.78,148.825,148.169,151.649,151.07,149.845,150.46,149.775,148.75,149.565,149.883,150.517,149.552,149.678,150.78,150.673,148.852,150.149,150.9,147.559,150.244,149.498,150.22,150.341,149.931,150.83,148.758,150.508,149.594,149.134,149.658,150.122,151.308,146.673,150.605,151.333,151.724,151.595,149.774,150.36,148.776,150.32,150.317,151.636,150.659,149.411,150.251,149.409,150.323,149.341,149.603,150.717,150.423,148.06,150.363},{150.132,149.219,150.927,150.489,149.088,148.224,149.043,149.618,150.091,150.318,151.795,150.626,149.736,149.526,149.947,150.465,151.514,148.594,153.27,151.652,149.127,149.536,149.943,150.203,149.2,150.782,150.158,150.545,150.396,150.606,150.103,150.274,148.694,151.895,148.554,148.359,149.777,149.521,150.579,150.01,149.348,150.422,150.791,149.774,151.896,149.271,150.541,150.259,149.762,149.578,150.891,151.422,151.619,148.117,149.072,149.493,152.491,150.219,150.854,151.079},{153.081,149.547,151.255,149.348,150.096,149.912,151.775,149.391,148.952,150.976,149.684,149.737,149.389,149.608,149.562,149.117,150.277,150.824,149.026,149.569,149.832,148.95,149.184,150.767,149.865,151.029,150.274,150.346,148.696,148.314,149.907,150.071,149.444,150.549,148.528,149.37,148.756,148.349,150.475,150.515,149.362,150.829,149.517,148.658,148.425,150.212,148.513,150.095,149.403,149.943,149.919,148.548,148.393,150.834,149.159,149.079,150.768,150.876,149.095,150.332},{149.411,150.619,150.427,150.595,151.592,147.768,150.577,149.881,151.57,148.464,150.43,150.413,149.645,148.974,149.48,148.941,150.417,149.188,149.634,148.634,150.294,148.604,149.339,149.111,150.491,151.111,148.619,149.006,149.265,149.082,150.656,150.959,149.92,148.989,151.23,150.721,152.342,149.759,149.264,150.456,149.42,149.466,147.738,149.721,150.962,147.966,150.732,149.954,149.405,149.059,152.565,150.337,151.224,150.198,150.208,150.249,151.505,148.469,151.061,151.684},{150.341,149.104,149.156,149.519,151.028,149.422,150.009,147.855,152.263,149.73,149.299,150.73,147.782,149.854,149.139,150.729,150.055,148.035,150.712,151.83,152.039,149.1,152.078,151.12,150.095,150.596,150.568,147.798,149.833,150.263,150.316,148.399,149.732,149.471,151.284,148.639,150.756,147.888,149.785,151.14,149.538,150.443,151.513,152.912,149.609,150.995,149.458,148.642,148.646,150.24,149.4,150.213,149.99,149.94,150.661,150.525,150.831,148.946,150.3,149.148},{149.014,149.171,149.588,149.971,150.587,151.578,149.493,151.265,150.476,150.379,149.48,147.699,149.649,150.851,148.766,149.821,149.319,150.03,149.822,151.415,151.042,149.335,150.916,149.113,151.688,150.621,151.866,150.413,148.974,151.232,149.921,150.781,151.369,149.726,151.071,148.793,149.856,150.134,149.69,150.034,151.58,150.493,150.898,149.893,150.127,150.539,149.684,149.163,151.131,148.81,150.181,149.59,150.103,149.722,149.413,148.61,148.467,148.654,149.054,149.706},{148.205,150.482,150.698,149.325,148.48,150.14,149.978,150.525,151.299,148.987,148.904,150.145,151.15,150.269,149.122,150.129,149.423,149.645,149.322,148.736,148.407,148.594,149.735,149.48,149.686,148.837,150.419,145.203,146.323,145.976,148.832,147.249,147.265,149.24,149.053,148.084,151.683,149.5,148.935,149.687,149.733,151.07,150.079,150.099,151.019,151.512,151.495,149.854,150.177,151.118,149.983,149.72,151.235,150.345,149.299,148.376,148.787,149.694,150.211,150.577},{148.266,149.638,151.357,148.502,150.669,149.697,151.635,150.344,150.538,149.464,151.1,149.095,149.507,149.284,149.093,151.324,149.865,149.99,150.194,150.778,147.429,150.259,151.598,148.914,146.251,146.815,149.898,146.272,146.153,146.81,146.807,147.79,145.205,149.544,146.293,146.042,148.672,149.987,150.649,150.74,150.986,148.789,149.271,151.466,148.609,149.846,151.288,149.675,149.7,148.533,149.979,149.388,149.18,151.522,149.739,148.317,149.454,148.622,150.757,149.043},{149.637,149.573,149.477,149.786,150.042,148.39,150.644,151.514,150.113,149.374,150.352,152.153,150.761,150.484,149.361,149.048,149.385,149.231,150.732,149.724,149.7,145.768,147.812,142.909,149.734,147.911,145.977,147.142,144.866,150.983,146.032,146.51,147.959,146.507,145.804,144.862,148.292,144.849,150.357,149.866,148.1,150.96,148.714,150.993,149.69,148.308,149.87,148.628,148.322,150.137,151.059,150.155,149.597,152.411,150.905,150.95,151.253,150.392,149.111,149.697},{150.228,151.011,149.433,149.367,152.304,150.438,150.309,151.5,147.285,149.496,148.462,150.037,149.012,152.487,151.233,149.633,151.226,150.327,148.919,149.469,149.945,149.458,148.35,147.913,148.458,146.001,147.561,151.268,149.548,150.174,148.847,150.835,148.802,147.893,146.064,149.691,145.471,144.936,148.142,151.348,150.721,149.545,149.612,150.922,150.291,149.171,149.386,150.134,150.218,150.866,150.949,151.276,150.9,149.954,150.183,150.275,149.473,149.85,148.115,150.657},{150.964,151.041,147.891,151.252,150.064,150.487,150.072,148.252,149.293,148.988,148.477,151.319,150.452,150.027,148.667,148.658,149.979,149.91,151.838,146.632,146.546,147.189,145.55,146.966,145.855,146.992,147.003,146.057,148.768,149.672,148.734,149.117,146.511,147.301,149.145,148.143,146.117,146.942,148.293,149.006,149.136,151.047,151.438,150.607,149.239,150.733,150.068,148.508,150.492,147.454,151.38,150.567,148.458,150.325,150.751,150.529,150.549,151.67,149.955,149.738},{148.494,149.352,147.991,151.516,148.588,151.933,150.9,149.323,151.017,147.786,150.382,149.848,150.427,151.53,151.56,149.849,148.921,148.851,145.489,147.75,148.084,143.949,145.233,148.869,147.43,150.958,148.158,147.078,148.125,147.579,145.524,146.741,150.571,145.457,143.451,142.503,140.863,146.616,147.419,148.954,149.815,150.333,150.861,148.843,147.981,150.731,151.242,150.522,149.622,150.43,150.218,151.136,151.8,147.705,151.012,150.147,151.005,148.736,149.057,151.991},{149.618,149.409,149.152,151.202,150.472,149.166,151.511,150.844,150.738,150.286,149.98,149.641,148.81,147.92,150.448,150.2,149.636,149.191,148.464,147.821,148.972,146.779,147.756,147.015,145.32,146.419,144.079,146.462,149.311,149.102,147.685,145.81,147.602,145.351,150.54,147.877,144.777,146.362,148.403,144.582,149.856,149.367,149.771,149.776,149.643,150.655,150.298,148.759,150.645,150.397,148.495,151.31,148.859,150.268,149.922,149.017,149.153,149.831,148.575,150.322},{149.7,147.301,148.376,151.16,150.749,148.95,149.143,149.063,150.973,149.364,148.944,149.136,151.16,148.739,149.468,150.859,148.797,147.552,147.419,143.852,143.044,148.147,146.359,147.775,147.615,151.707,149.131,146.968,144.65,147.96,148.421,145.227,147.407,150.302,146.228,148.418,142.205,145.204,148.165,152.121,147.574,148.613,149.602,150.92,150.412,147.504,150.487,150.02,149.786,147.893,149.378,149.293,150.982,150.768,148.663,149.679,151.226,150.658,148.995,150.247},{149.938,151.348,151.725,148.245,148.273,150.482,149.614,149.107,149.645,150.653,149.792,147.735,150.907,148.851,149.564,149.618,152.104,148.085,144.142,147.408,146.854,143.565,143.873,148.577,145.167,148.418,148.212,146.364,150.762,145.276,149.822,146.729,149.423,146.958,148.263,148.444,145.854,149.088,145.915,144.047,147.374,145.19,149.068,149.428,148.574,151.233,149.824,151.402,151.863,151.55,151.376,149.956,151.265,149.632,149.612,150.563,150.225,150.862,149.627,150.016},{149.915,149.257,149.642,148.234,152.181,147.743,151.024,148.994,150.22,150.102,150.956,151.792,149.868,151.732,149.628,150.678,145.814,149.749,148.364,144.53,150.744,144.718,147.514,145.403,145.717,145.708,148.327,145.001,146.107,149.299,146.066,146.541,146.854,141.993,145.214,146.156,146.041,148.477,148.074,148.312,143.707,144.764,149.896,150.146,149.327,149.577,150.51,149.277,149.697,150.721,150.285,150.368,151.403,150.667,148.451,149.967,149.998,151.132,149.955,151.073},{149.759,149.908,149.182,149.572,150.621,151.268,149.477,150.978,151.838,150.383,149.762,149.076,149.623,150.997,150.493,148.485,144.415,147.49,149.937,147.796,148.406,143.943,142.492,146.697,148.577,143.853,147.25,146.066,145.705,143.779,146.221,143.129,147.257,149.221,151.713,149.324,145.682,145.753,147.479,147.861,147.522,146.052,143.938,149.731,150.064,150.113,150.448,148.894,151.444,150.211,149.332,149.784,148.941,148.995,149.181,149.692,150.563,148.937,149.277,149.998},{150.921,149.393,151.814,150.987,150.835,149.603,149.709,149.647,148.736,149.645,149.011,150.509,148.759,150.798,150.333,151.249,145.602,148.536,144.75,148.227,146.952,147.063,146.959,140.156,145.188,145.923,144.362,146.049,144.363,147.29,143.463,147.264,146.597,146.434,142.99,142.215,148.606,144.866,147.715,146.573,148.414,148.146,147.887,150.069,149.285,149.493,150.942,150.241,148.528,149.035,149.99,151.132,150.3,149.69,149.354,149.123,148.298,150.41,150.172,149.727},{148.947,151.687,150.339,148.561,150.262,149.979,150.765,150.017,147.885,147.747,149.312,148.984,150.323,147.954,150.027,148.139,149.882,145.377,150.38,145.986,147.427,146.262,145.009,146.551,149.746,143.923,148.833,151.302,146.304,143.245,145.535,144.268,144.62,147.296,146.234,149.315,149.391,146.037,146.837,145.002,145.01,145.033,145.883,149.788,150.54,151.174,150.183,150.896,151.286,151.008,148.607,150.019,149.609,149.122,148.991,151.037,146.997,148.767,148.815,150.435},{150.473,149.198,149.382,149.297,150.679,149.973,150.604,151.215,149.563,148.576,150.082,150.187,149.342,148.103,149.844,150.853,148.93,147.466,149.479,144.966,150.218,145.454,150.045,150.628,150.92,145.563,143.95,142.005,146.857,146.615,147.759,144.723,145.709,146.763,149.008,146.218,143.469,147.664,146.863,145.04,143.555,143.96,148.855,150.819,149.43,149.779,150.11,150.214,149.936,149.309,149.392,149.138,150.515,149.348,149.444,149.452,148.541,149.977,151.025,150.819},{148.639,151.23,148.652,148.16,148.782,151.074,150.546,151.968,150.683,150.111,150.821,148.359,151.272,147.834,149.448,150.278,146.669,146.662,146.974,147.628,145.933,146.271,149.938,143.861,146.083,149.16,149.315,147.95,145.911,145.155,149.066,151.12,147.765,146.509,146.954,147.804,142.424,151.636,150.092,143.996,146.025,148.703,144.007,149.153,151.288,149.924,149.691,150.004,148.922,151.276,149.313,149.403,151.165,150.009,151.726,149.648,148.414,149.6,148.035,150.356},{150.821,149.423,149.017,149.114,150.205,149.728,149.046,151.062,149.647,150.791,150.95,150.175,151.02,150.439,150.254,149.746,143.895,146.375,148.831,148.068,146.228,145.368,146.741,144.557,144.697,152.027,140.995,144.608,146.513,150.044,145.665,147.99,150.072,147.541,147.602,152.102,146.893,145.457,145.706,144.087,149.144,147.81,149.427,149.07,149.88,149.715,148.595,150.789,151.352,150.652,149.525,150.364,150.908,148.854,148.915,150.227,148.839,148.85,149.884,148.989},{151.107,150.578,149.169,150.51,149.728,148.627,149.831,149.007,148.298,149.518,153.018,150.545,149.61,150.927,148.665,149.707,144.302,149.849,147.104,145.117,148.814,147.84,146.419,147.113,147.735,146.14,150.896,144.895,144.415,145.743,149.061,148.203,146.026,145.699,144.906,146.296,145.519,149.417,147.694,144.694,147.117,145.794,147.046,150.247,148.596,148.288,148.814,151.252,150.626,149.526,149.635,149.415,150.891,150.702,151.094,148.082,149.138,149.498,148.956,149.677},{150.73,151.413,149.413,151.171,150.618,150.167,148.28,150.497,149.411,150.564,149.147,150.301,151.22,149.278,150.813,149.057,144.313,145.995,142.772,147.769,145.652,147.756,147.742,146.107,149.8,150.78,147.694,143.57,147.762,144.646,145.139,149.378,147.772,149.163,146.701,143.939,146.23,144.818,145.011,146.343,147.254,148.528,146.846,149.671,150.442,151.261,149.229,150.306,150.006,149.318,149.668,149.609,149.236,150.462,151.049,151.518,149.783,150.591,147.139,150.053},{150.551,149.195,148.91,151.647,150.74,147.287,150.585,150.218,150.803,150.329,148.833,148.997,150.126,150.099,151.413,149.376,148.816,147.882,143.706,147.365,144.371,148.296,145.747,147.286,150.321,145.502,146.527,143.247,146.328,142.605,146.064,148.003,150.393,149.286,145.245,148.786,148.076,148.784,146.549,146.49,146.63,148.967,148.121,151.077,149.822,149.55,148.728,149.57,149.439,152.295,148.792,150.066,151.313,150.658,150.232,148.232,149.115,150.268,149.407,151.064},{149.385,150.45,149.186,151.769,149.549,148.845,150.965,151.31,149.837,149.463,148.457,150.415,150.029,150.716,149.246,148.852,149.55,148.119,148.141,145.875,147.611,146.377,148.056,146.993,147.002,145.813,145.138,146.031,146.539,146.034,142.143,145.138,145.899,146.598,146.242,147.021,148.885,144.15,149.572,147.564,144.157,151.093,150.403,149.791,149.745,150.89,149.865,148.629,152.056,149.451,151.835,147.974,149.817,150.33,149.951,150.672,150.737,149.403,148.988,151.389},{150.383,149.829,150.732,150.657,150.506,151.192,149.95,149.37,147.992,149.669,151.995,149.378,149.481,149.108,149.756,150.543,151.273,152.3,148.125,145.545,145.861,146.713,147.175,144.236,148.726,146.827,143.676,146.053,145.816,145.689,149.517,145.036,145.346,146.789,143.534,150.183,146.223,147.398,150.461,148.748,145.577,150.534,150.763,148.915,149.909,150.717,149.887,151.131,150.503,149.627,150.063,149.177,148.746,151.931,149.875,151.401,150.627,150.055,150.244,151.215},{150.617,150.266,149.446,151.637,148.481,148.995,150.292,148.655,150.476,150.721,151.865,150.756,149.179,150.093,149.295,149.705,149.117,149.326,149.371,146.945,146.152,146.803,148.302,148.769,145.965,148.467,148.598,146.284,149.516,146.833,145.984,147.915,145.253,147.822,148.463,147.401,149.185,145.104,147.762,148.929,149.22,149.819,151.508,150.217,149.386,148.877,150.732,150.721,148.231,151.666,149.04,149.989,149.823,149.509,148.33,148.655,148.13,148.911,149.432,150.662},{149.268,150.799,149.912,150.574,148.212,150.796,148.305,151.003,150.403,149.552,148.78,148.859,149.43,148.79,149.401,150.229,151.162,149.972,150.564,147.361,149.863,148.051,148.561,146.619,147.983,148.566,146.36,148.138,143.168,149.595,144.137,146.126,145.555,145.113,148.724,149.456,145.375,145.337,147.269,145.88,150.221,150.975,149.862,151.599,150.151,151.466,149.976,151.462,150.055,150.049,148.984,150.132,151.072,150.296,151.351,150.447,151.807,149.834,150.55,150.758},{148.976,149.461,150.744,147.745,150.008,150.343,150.96,149.773,150.626,148.442,150.595,150.883,149.836,150.219,149.783,150.496,149.471,148.322,147.905,150.472,146.613,149.223,146.102,148.268,143.366,147.092,144.768,147.476,149.185,147.307,145.997,151.588,149.,148.049,146.606,146.444,142.938,147.424,145.607,149.65,150.13,150.5,151.677,151.54,148.792,148.343,149.313,150.897,150.175,151.388,148.913,151.328,149.709,149.123,149.545,149.932,151.969,148.816,149.766,149.795},{150.637,150.942,148.847,151.124,149.365,148.211,150.603,149.93,149.767,150.037,150.145,149.796,150.901,149.318,151.095,150.041,150.301,148.135,150.067,149.875,152.522,146.512,148.584,148.269,144.343,144.689,147.6,142.634,147.252,149.793,146.491,148.53,150.209,147.11,146.402,150.015,147.61,148.59,150.386,149.039,150.097,148.352,148.311,150.492,149.13,151.281,151.131,148.429,150.443,149.844,149.154,151.15,149.174,150.804,150.403,150.945,150.571,150.291,148.731,151.155},{148.886,149.693,149.182,147.358,149.393,150.445,151.489,151.93,149.466,150.002,149.344,149.448,151.402,150.453,150.568,148.68,150.821,150.027,148.654,151.06,149.836,149.348,150.34,146.865,143.608,148.055,144.161,146.031,145.548,145.633,146.287,147.889,146.844,144.538,151.196,149.131,149.063,150.74,150.284,150.477,151.681,149.444,150.892,147.48,150.822,149.171,150.688,150.283,151.661,149.515,149.69,150.106,151.096,149.691,150.211,150.051,149.878,148.787,148.626,150.53},{151.457,149.68,149.022,152.979,149.267,149.128,150.151,149.815,149.87,150.427,149.622,150.749,149.146,149.317,149.518,149.172,147.866,149.982,149.585,151.824,149.436,148.854,149.926,151.559,149.124,146.213,146.24,145.702,144.786,147.665,146.015,145.327,147.139,145.321,150.446,148.538,151.253,150.103,151.133,150.446,149.583,149.58,150.677,152.373,149.523,148.288,148.552,149.376,151.531,149.634,148.833,148.669,149.104,148.494,150.549,151.351,148.412,149.741,150.304,147.565},{149.697,149.517,151.597,148.42,150.302,149.594,149.038,151.072,149.713,150.25,148.185,150.085,151.526,150.772,148.022,150.527,148.982,149.516,151.25,151.557,150.692,148.915,149.448,150.748,149.675,149.688,149.463,147.955,149.2,149.39,149.605,150.305,150.08,149.201,149.345,149.422,149.734,150.411,149.418,150.75,149.326,151.115,151.033,150.299,149.636,148.938,152.157,149.39,149.285,150.282,151.203,149.988,151.004,150.613,150.172,150.799,148.985,149.821,150.166,151.079},{150.261,148.408,149.999,149.634,151.557,151.442,149.429,150.443,150.367,149.327,150.364,149.774,149.625,150.896,150.885,149.722,150.56,150.653,151.536,149.584,149.724,149.718,148.608,149.5,148.666,149.874,150.278,151.204,149.851,150.021,147.971,149.635,152.02,151.557,149.896,150.685,149.98,148.477,148.582,151.015,148.605,150.312,149.391,147.689,150.734,151.065,150.104,151.581,151.693,150.802,151.221,150.906,151.517,150.441,149.32,149.306,149.531,148.08,151.145,149.37},{150.174,150.674,150.088,153.095,150.428,148.569,148.556,149.43,149.503,150.42,149.691,149.875,150.055,148.827,149.303,151.227,149.519,150.354,151.707,152.6,150.738,152.75,150.511,150.422,149.045,149.88,147.978,149.921,151.134,148.809,150.911,147.547,148.948,149.457,149.623,150.278,150.457,149.252,150.409,149.398,149.717,150.724,150.881,149.843,150.828,148.693,149.637,150.751,151.599,148.861,148.825,149.457,147.539,150.347,150.973,149.803,151.266,150.389,148.03,150.652},{152.621,152.193,151.076,150.174,148.94,149.281,150.643,149.71,148.665,148.875,150.085,147.938,149.885,149.207,148.529,149.692,149.436,151.122,150.674,149.442,149.038,149.388,149.364,151.08,149.882,148.915,150.172,149.59,149.902,149.254,150.496,148.39,150.701,148.899,149.145,150.197,147.486,149.731,148.242,149.599,149.475,150.758,149.683,149.092,150.062,150.332,149.807,150.506,150.194,149.496,150.115,149.978,148.12,150.033,150.267,149.066,148.483,149.901,149.166,150.858},{150.076,149.664,148.465,149.366,150.727,150.859,148.377,150.81,149.642,147.953,148.161,150.882,151.028,151.017,150.063,150.606,149.48,149.701,149.602,151.362,152.303,150.756,151.913,150.755,150.412,150.447,150.815,150.18,149.085,151.016,149.432,150.949,149.937,149.387,150.412,147.687,149.257,152.547,153.757,149.948,150.686,150.383,148.864,147.812,150.144,150.273,150.79,149.36,147.856,149.206,151.026,149.823,149.045,149.551,150.643,148.656,148.969,149.772,149.929,149.208},{147.514,152.093,148.965,149.32,149.219,150.192,151.389,149.934,149.854,149.312,149.557,149.891,150.246,148.066,150.61,149.321,149.657,148.711,150.079,149.787,149.469,150.073,149.684,149.296,149.803,151.255,151.308,150.422,150.18,150.491,151.199,149.387,150.378,149.571,148.286,151.27,151.107,150.332,150.69,150.374,150.241,150.579,149.301,150.975,149.895,150.318,149.611,150.054,151.109,149.077,149.703,149.566,149.792,150.509,148.114,149.073,152.221,149.608,149.259,149.956},{148.96,150.505,148.556,148.96,149.18,149.859,149.488,148.637,149.356,151.101,147.363,150.303,148.946,152.618,149.018,150.389,151.57,149.272,150.076,150.059,149.803,150.372,150.339,151.145,150.32,148.53,150.231,150.869,150.85,147.995,149.604,149.417,150.521,151.87,151.422,148.422,149.068,150.626,149.841,151.4,150.572,150.138,150.985,151.067,149.583,149.784,150.65,149.98,149.381,149.904,149.239,150.271,149.718,149.469,150.699,148.916,147.091,150.049,149.061,148.724},{150.913,150.006,150.265,148.882,150.113,151.376,151.425,150.503,151.387,149.592,149.283,151.681,152.123,150.741,150.678,149.594,148.568,150.392,149.579,151.868,149.441,149.152,149.648,151.86,148.991,149.555,149.725,149.491,147.821,149.752,149.734,152.722,150.159,150.152,150.128,148.908,151.82,149.078,149.518,146.712,149.753,148.983,150.851,147.592,147.671,150.73,150.264,150.321,150.627,149.109,150.929,150.892,148.471,149.987,150.584,151.667,149.664,150.998,151.45,150.545},{150.66,148.265,148.616,149.546,149.158,150.008,150.269,150.722,150.276,149.42,150.873,149.909,150.864,150.111,148.562,150.,150.361,151.238,150.434,150.669,151.04,151.094,149.818,150.695,150.036,149.531,149.675,148.679,151.814,150.635,150.151,149.289,151.434,149.627,149.897,151.196,150.179,150.052,150.503,150.536,148.829,150.333,149.437,151.29,149.564,152.003,149.909,150.12,152.26,148.629,150.642,150.796,150.913,150.344,150.963,150.976,149.644,152.118,150.702,150.042},{151.221,147.646,148.644,149.787,149.118,150.572,152.125,148.886,148.807,152.299,149.92,148.605,150.001,151.246,149.215,149.086,151.404,148.656,149.988,149.647,148.413,152.689,151.141,148.295,150.321,147.797,149.208,151.242,149.033,150.016,148.356,149.612,149.852,149.928,150.183,149.803,148.722,151.043,148.218,149.079,150.595,149.625,149.902,149.464,151.343,148.37,148.047,149.38,150.142,151.628,151.259,149.958,150.236,151.309,151.093,151.096,151.4,151.41,150.566,149.367},{150.096,149.685,150.857,149.786,150.429,148.837,149.345,149.818,151.539,150.544,148.218,149.866,151.169,151.059,152.096,149.907,148.245,150.178,149.529,150.129,150.054,151.211,151.323,149.788,151.358,150.641,150.235,149.999,150.792,149.538,149.305,150.01,149.228,151.39,150.667,149.767,148.975,149.563,150.784,150.833,150.237,148.947,149.705,149.63,149.65,150.723,151.07,149.305,150.071,149.028,148.945,148.143,151.346,149.323,149.964,151.508,152.465,149.776,151.4,150.191},{150.427,150.19,150.817,149.813,149.962,149.681,150.525,151.333,150.076,148.843,150.696,150.161,150.383,149.091,151.371,151.92,149.268,149.02,148.441,150.242,150.056,150.593,149.727,149.324,151.198,149.998,150.047,148.673,150.045,149.67,149.87,147.855,151.588,150.311,149.79,150.175,149.75,150.318,147.41,151.784,150.229,151.956,149.787,150.796,149.549,150.471,148.167,151.443,150.442,150.311,149.966,150.297,150.307,149.414,150.65,148.123,149.707,151.617,149.278,151.087}}
};
```

Comment: This may be a stupid answer, but it seems to me that those numbers are intensity values of a matrix. Have you tried ListDensityPlot[oPic, PlotRange -> All] ? It gives a reasonable output (or at list, it seems something that could make sense :D )

Comment: `oPic` dimensions is `{1, n, m}` so you need to e.g. drop the first one. Then adjust values and it will work: `ImageAdjust @ Image @ First @ oPic` - is that what you are after?

Comment: @Fraccalo it is work, but the result is wrong, the original picture is black-white, and the outcome of our approach is a color image.
@ Kuba thank you a lot; it is work. Before I post the question, I flattened the data, but not adjust the values. Why I have to adjust values of a matrix?

Comment: Updating my comment, a more nice output is obtained with: ListDensityPlot[oPic, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 0, AspectRatio -> Dimensions[oPic[[1]]]] . Which is also similar to the output from @Kuba comment. You can play with the various options of Plots and customise the plot quite a lot :) Hope this may help you

Comment: @Fraccalo Your last comment seems to go a very long way towards answering the question. Would you convert it into an answer?

Comment: @MarcoB Sure, that sounds like a good idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning a comment into an answer:

```
ListDensityPlot[oPic
,PlotRange -> All
,ColorFunction -> GrayLevel
,InterpolationOrder -> 0
,AspectRatio -> Dimensions[oPic[[1]]]
]
```

This lets you the possibility of playing with the Plot options for customising the output.

Comment: Thank you! (+1)